# How can I find if there is a gap/s between transforms array?

Tags: unity, c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < cubes.Length; i++)
{  
    if(bricks[i].transform.position.z == 1)
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(bricks[i].transform.position, )
    }
}
```

I want to find all the places where the distance between two cubes is > 0.
For example if there is a gap between index 6 and index 7, then give me the gap position it's empty space, but give me this position where there was should be a cube.

Each couple of cubes check if there is a gap between them and return the gap position.

I have a maze randomly generated and there are some entrances I want to find the entrances by checking for gaps each gap position is entrance.

This is the maze create class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Maze
{
    //Grid size
    public int width;
    public int height;

    //Store grid
    private bool[,] grid;
    //Generate random directions to move
    private System.Random rg;

    //Start position
    public int startX;
    public int startY;

    //Public getter
    public bool[,] Grid
    {
        get { return grid; }
    }

    //Constructor of the grid for setting values
    public Maze(int width, int height, System.Random rg)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.rg = rg;
    }

    //Generate the grid
    public void Generate()
    {
        grid = new bool[width, height];

        startX = 1;
        startY = 1;

        grid[startX, startY] = true;

        MazeDigger(startX, startY);
    }

    void MazeDigger(int x, int y)
    {
        int[] directions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        //We create random array of directions
        HelpingTools.Shuffle(directions, rg);

        //We are looping over all the directions
        for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (directions[i] == 1)
            {
                if (y - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y - 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y - 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y - 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y - 2);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 2)
            {
                if (x - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x - 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x - 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x - 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x - 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 3)
            {
                if (x + 2 >= width - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x + 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x + 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x + 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x + 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 4)
            {
                if (y + 2 >= height - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y + 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y + 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y + 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y + 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the maze generate script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Maze maze;
    public int mazeWidth;
    public int mazeHeight;
    public string mazeSeed;
    public GameObject wallPrefab;

    private GameObject wall;
    private GameObject wallCorner;
    private System.Random mazeRG;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        mazeRG = new System.Random();

        if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0)
            //mazeWidth++;

        if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0)
        {
            //mazeHeight++;
        }

        maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG);
        GenerateMaze();
    }

    public void GenerateMaze()
    {
        maze.Generate();
        DrawMaze();
    }

    void DrawMaze()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == true)
                {
                    CreateMaze(position, transform, 0, mazeRG.Next(0, 3) * 90);
                }
            }
        }

        var bricks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MazeBrick");

        bricks[bricks.Length - 1].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;

        //bricks[Random.Range(0, bricks.Length - 1)].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;

        for (int i = 0; i < bricks.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bricks[i].transform.position.x == maze.startX &&
                bricks[i].transform.position.z == maze.startY)
            {
                bricks[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            }

            if(bricks[i].transform.position.z == 1)
            {
                var distance = Vector3.Distance(bricks[i].transform.position, )
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateMaze(Vector3 position, Transform parent, int sortingOrder, float rotation)
    {
        GameObject mazePrefab = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        mazePrefab.transform.SetParent(parent);
        mazePrefab.transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);
        mazePrefab.tag = "MazeBrick";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        
    }
}
```

And the HelpingTools script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HelpingTools : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array, System.Random rg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = rg.Next(i, array.Length);

            T tempItem = array[randomIndex];

            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = tempItem;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

The maze is generate randomly. with random entrances/exits depending on what you are define as entrances or exits but for this example lets say they are all entrances.

I positioned the main camera in one of the entrances but I want that after the maze has generated to position the camera automatic randomly on one of the entrances.

Later on I want the camera to enter the selected entrance and travel through the maze. but for now first I want to find all the entrances and position the camera in front of one of them.

[image: Maze image example]

I tried this to fill the gaps between the bricks of the grid but it's not working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bricks.Length; i++)
{
    var brick = bricks[i];

    for (int x = 0; x < bricks.Length; x++)
    {
        if (brick.transform.position.z == 1)
        {
            var distance = Vector3.Distance(brick.transform.position, bricks[x].transform.position);
            if (distance > brick.transform.localScale.x)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(distance == 1f)
            {
                // josh.position.x + (mark.position.x - josh.position.x) / 2;

                var block = Instantiate(wallPrefab, new Vector3(bricks[x].transform.position.x + 1,0,brick.transform.position.z), wallPrefab.transform.rotation);
                block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm trying this loop :

```
for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == false)
                {
                    var t = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
                    t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then it will fill all gaps in yellow and also will fill the surrounding of the maze. How do I fill only the gaps of the outer of the maze ?

[image: maze filled gaps]

This is is not working either :

```
for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                if (x == mazeWidth - 1 || y == mazeHeight - 1)
                {

                    Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                    if (maze.Grid[x, y] == false)
                    {
                        var t = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Updating with my last testing :

```
for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == false)
                {
                    if (x == mazeWidth - 1 || x == 1 || y == mazeHeight - 1 || y == 1)
                    {
                        var t = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but still the result is not good enough.

And another update, I'm almost there.

I still don't get it yet if the maze size is 30 on 30 why when I click on bricks that on the outer of the maze the Z position is 27 and not 30 ?

And why some bricks are out of the outer of the maze ?

```
for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == false)
                {
                    if (x == 27 || x == 1f || y == 27 || y == 1f)
                    {
                        var t = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The result is :

[image: Maze]

In this screenshot the top show a brick outside the maze what is this ? X is at 1 but Z is at 29 than on the bottom I clicked on a brick in the outer maze area and it is the z on 27.

So why its coloring some on z 29 ? and why the maze is size 27 on 27 but I set it to be 30 on 30 ?

And maybe the maze is 30 on 30 but all the rows and columns from 30 to 27 are empty gaps ?

I don't understand it yet.

Comment: What did not work? Is your array of cubes called cubes oder bricks? Distance will always return something greater than 0 if their centers are not on top of each other. How are your bricks organized if you have only a single index for them.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your `grid` in your maze class represents your full maze. You can simply iterate through the first and last row/ column of x/y and check if it is true or false to find if there is a wall or not.

Comment: @Zibelas can you show me please how to do it ? I updated my question with what I tried and I can fill the whole maze gaps in yellow but I want on to fill only the gaps in the outer area of the maze not like in the screenshot.

Comment: You have it almost, your loop goes over your full maze, but you just want the outer rows of it.

Comment: @Zibelas can you please correct my last try in my question ? it's close but still not good enough.

Comment: I also noticed that if I set in the inspector the maze size to be 30 on 30 and then in the editor when the game is running and I select the outer bricks I see that X and Y are 1 and 27 why the outer is 27 ? if the maze size is 30 on 30 why when I select the X width I see it's 27 and not 30 the outer ?

Comment: I forgot to add the HelpingTools script so I added it now to my question with the other scripts at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets address your points one by one and a possible missconception of your maze

- Your start index is wrong. The array is zero based but you set the start point  to 1 in the Maze script line 40 and 41.
- I might be wrong here but to me your maze looks inverted. That means you do not travel between the blocks but the path it meant to be the blocks that are generated. Assuming this is true, that brings us to the next point (even if it was not true, the next point is still valid)
- Now you should know the reason for line 23 and 27 in the MazeGenerator. You can't generate a maze with an even side. If you have a maze by the size of 5, you have wall-space-wall-space-wall, but if it is size 6, you are not ending on the same kind of tile as you are starting.